# recaptcha challenge issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am trying to configure an application for my client and I am using recaptcha for spam control and I am using ruby on rails (also using this plugin http://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/).

My client wants an easy challenge as he is not able to read, its too hard. Is there any way I can make the challenge easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReCaptcha is a third-party captcha, and I don't believe they give you any control over what captchas they serve.

It is true that a big complaint people have about captchas is that they can be hard to read, but if they were easy to read, they would also be easy for spammers to get past. You really can't win. :(

The good news with recaptcha in particular is that often you only have to get one of the two words right to pass the test, and it's usually the easier-to-read one. If you give your best effort with the other one, recaptcha will often let you through. (see the recaptcha site for details of how it works and why this is the case)

Comment: thanks for the info... I dint know if you get one of the words right captcha would let through... thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use some logic questions instead of confusing captcha images. There is a [plugin](http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/4/21/actsastextcaptcha) for this.